# React Native and React Native Navigation - Handle Back (goBack) issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

thank you for taking time to read & answer this question. I'll give my best to explain the issue I'm having.

The `HomeStack` component holds bottom navigation for four screens. One screen that is giving me a headache is `ProjectsStack`

```js
export const ProjectsStack = (): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <ProjectsStackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='ProjectsScreen' screenOptions={defaultScreenOptions}>
      <ProjectsStackNav.Screen name='ProjectsScreen' component={ProjectsScreen} />
      <ProjectsStackNav.Screen name='CompletedProjectsScreen' component={CompletedProjectsScreen} />
      <ProjectsStackNav.Screen name='ProjectTasksScreen' component={ProjectTasksScreen} />
      <ProjectsStackNav.Screen name='CompletedProjectsTasksScreen' component={ProjectTasksScreen} />
    </ProjectsStackNav.Navigator>
  );
};
```

As you can see the `ProjectTasksScreen` is a component that renders a project based on the props => if it's open it will render `ProjectTasksScreen` otherwise it will render `CompletedProjectsTasksScreen` which is basically the same screen (reusability at its finest lol)

In order to go to the `CompletedProjectsTasksScreen`, you need to come from `ProjectTasksScreen`.

Now, the issue is when you want to go back from `CompletedProjectsTasksScreen` it will not go to `ProjectTasksScreen`, rather it will navigate to the previous screen of `ProjectTasksScreen` which is `ProjectsScreen`.

Is there a better solution to this problem than refactoring everything into it's screen & component?

Answer (score 1):

`navigation.push` method instead of `navigation.navigate` may resolve your issue
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times

Comment: Solves the back issue but got another one, this adds two screens to the stack & I have to click back two times :(